# Rails 4: Forbid creating a parent object when associated one with specified attribute already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-attributes

I have a user and profile objects that have one-to-one relationship. Profile object has a facebook_id parameter.
I need to create user and through nested attributes corresponding profile unless profile with the specified facebook_id already exists in the database.

Please, help me with the right approach. I tried to add the following to my user.rb:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :social_profile#, :reject_if => proc {|attributes| Profile.where(:facebook_id=>attributes['facebook_id']).first}
```

That prevents creating profile object with the same facebook_id. But it anyway creates a user object without any associated profile at all which is unwanted.
How can I forbid creating a user object in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply add a unique index on the database table of the SocialMedia model. Also you can add a validation:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :facebook_id
```

And in your User model you would test for presence and existence:

```
validate_presence_of :social_media_id
validate :social_profile_exists

protected

def social_profile_exists
  errors.add(:social_media_id, "does not exist") unless SocialProfile.exists?(social_media_id)
end
```

Also maybe this would already work:

```
validates_associated :social_media
```

should ensure that the associated record itself is valid.

Comment: Thanks for reply. In some cases I need to add a bunch of users to database and it will be interrupted by validation check. But I just need such users to be silently skipped.

Comment: Well, you cann write your own custom validations (basically extend the social_profile_exists method) and skip it whenever you don't need it. But validations would be the right place, how exactly to set them up may differ for exact use case. I just based my answer on the information you gave in your question, can always be fine tuned.